# Selecting multiple rows using WHERE [key] without using AND in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this called `order_status`.

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| order_status_id | language_id | name              |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
|               2 |           1 | Processing        |
|               3 |           1 | Shipped           |
|               7 |           1 | Canceled          |
|               5 |           1 | Complete          |
|               8 |           1 | Denied            |
|               9 |           1 | Canceled Reversal |
|              10 |           1 | Failed            |
|              11 |           1 | Refunded          |
|              12 |           1 | Reversed          |
|              13 |           1 | Chargeback        |
|               1 |           1 | Pending           |
|              16 |           1 | Voided            |
|              15 |           1 | Processed         |
|              14 |           1 | Expired           |
|              17 |           1 | Confirmed         |
|              18 |           1 | Cash On Delivery  |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I am currently working on a query where I can select multiple `order_status_id`s.

Normally you would be able to select multiple rows like this:

`SELECT FROM order_status WHERE order_status_id = 1 AND order_status_id = 2`

The above command would select the `order_status_id` `1` and `2`.

However, I was wondering if you could simply do:

`SELECT FROM order_status WHERE order_status_id = (1,2)` without having to rewriting `AND order_status_id = 2` multiple times.

Trying that, I was given the error: `ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

My question is - how do I select multiple rows using `WHERE` without using `AND` multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use `in` is

`WHERE order_status_id in (1,2)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: I received the following error: `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION order_online_db.order_status_id does not exist`

Comment: You missed an `in` in between. The final query is `select * from oc_order_status WHERE order_status_id in (1,15);` Thanks for the docs!